# How to copy contentFiles of NuGet package references via MSBuild Copy task

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-standard, editorconfig

We have several repositories and each one has its own .editorconfig. Obviously, these are not synced, which is why I would like to distribute the .editorconfig from our framework solution (along with other files) via NuGet package to all our repositories/solutions and copy it via a simple Copy build Task to the solution directory.

I attempted to do the following:

Create a project "EditorConfigDistribution", which is supposed to contain the master .editorconfig file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NoDefaultExcludes>true</NoDefaultExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=".editorconfig">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>false</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\content</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This all works as expected and I do get the desired .editorconfig file in my project from the other solutions and it is referenced as shortcut in a folder content/.editorconfig (see [EditorConfigConsumer Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4tLc.png)).
The file is only a reference to `C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\editorconfigdistribution\1.0.0\contentFiles\any\any\content\.editorconfig`.

Now, I want to copy that .editorconfig file via build task:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EditorConfigDistribution" Version="1.0.0">
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyEditorConfig" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EditorConfigFileToCopy Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\content\.editorconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(EditorConfigFileToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.." SkipUnchangedFiles="true" UseHardlinksIfPossible="false" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However, I do get the following error:

```
Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\weberma9\source\repos\<some_path>\EditorConfigConsumer\content\.editorconfig" because it was not found. (20, 5)
```

I can understand that the file (since it is a shortcut) cannot be found, but I just cannot figure out a way to reference that shortcut correctly in my build task.
What do I need to change in that line `<EditorConfigFileToCopy Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\content\.editorconfig" />`?

Of course, if you have better approaches to my general problem - I'm glad to hear about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425012/dotnet-core-nuget-package-copying-content-files-on-restore/70713807#70713807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for my problem:
I not only provide the .editorconfig, but also the Copy-Build task via my *EditorConfigDistribution* project, which looks like this now:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NoDefaultExcludes>true</NoDefaultExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\.editorconfig">
      <Link>Rules\.editorconfig</Link>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>false</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <PackagePath>Rules\</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\**">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>false</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The .props file is straightforward and due to the convention that <package_id>.props and <package_id>.target are added to projects that consume the package (see [Include MSBuild props and targets in a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package)), it will always be executed before 'BeforeBuild'.

EditorConfigDistribution.props (placed in build folder):

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="CopyEditorConfig" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EditorConfigFilesToCopy Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Rules\.editorconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(EditorConfigFilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir).." SkipUnchangedFiles="true" UseHardlinksIfPossible="false" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```